# Deserializing a JSON Array to a Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Tags: c#, json, list, dictionary, deserialization

My ASP.NET program receive the Following JSON string:

```
{
    "key1" : "value1"
    "fileName" : [
        "filename1.docx",
        "filename2.xlsx"
    ]
}
```

I try to deserialize the JSON string with this line

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, List<String>>>(json)
```

But I get this error

```
Error Converting value "key1" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
```

Any solution?

Comment: "key1" : "value1" where is comma ","   ---  "key1" : "value1", "fileName" : [
        "filename1.docx",
        "filename2.xlsx"
    ]--

Comment: Please can you show us the full Json that you recieve?

Comment: you're json data format is incorrect. add comma ',' after `"key1" : "value1"`

Answer (score 2):

Create a class like this

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    public string key1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> fileName { get; set; }
}
```

and change the `Dictionary<String, List<String>>` to `RootObject`

```cs
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reiterating @phantasm's answer:

The JSON is incorrect. It is missing a comma. Below is the correct JSON.

```
{
    "key1" : "value1",
    "fileName" : [
        "filename1.docx",
        "filename2.xlsx"
    ]
}
```